# Call inner function from Chrome Dev Tools

Tags: javascript, function, google-chrome

I have a function with a second function inside:

```
var a = function(){
   function b(){
      alert("b() called!");
   }
}
a();
```

`a()` is called on load. Because I need to debug something, I open Chrome's console and want to call `b()`. But it's not working. I searched here a little bit and I found that I need to make some sort of breakpoint inside the `a()` function, but it is not working.

What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I searched here littlebit and I found, that I need to make some sort of breakpoint inside a() function, but it is not working.

It's hard to set a breakpoint within `a` because `a`'s *only* content is `b`, which is never called.

Add something in `a` that you can put a breakpoint on, such as a `console.log` statement:

```
var a = function(){
   console.log("a called");
   function b(){
      alert("b() called!");
   }
}
a();
```

Now you can load the page, set a breakpoint on the `console.log` in `a`, reload the page (since `a` has already run on the first page load), and then you can call `b`.

Comment: *(I did double-check that Chrome doesn't immediately optimize `b` away in the above, just to be sure.)*

Comment: I added console.log() to a() and started Chrome. I added breakpoint in sources and refreshed page. Breakpoint will disappear after reload. What I am doing wrong?

Comment: @KarelTest: I don't know, the breakpoint persists when I do the same thing. You could resort to adding the `debugger;` statement just before the `console.log`. That's a hardcoded breakpoint.

Comment: I dont knwo what I am doing wrong but JS file always change after refresh